# Having trouble with the "bottom padding method"

Tags: html, css

You can see my sample site uploaded [HERE.](http://www.granthoneymoon.com/Most_insightful_posts.html) (it's the 3 buttons below the NEXT button at the bottom)

I'm trying to use the bottom padding method of keeping a div's height/width ratio (using bottom padding as a % of the width to create the entire height of the div with a div inside it set to absolute positioning and 100% width and height.). But, in certain browsers (like my samsung galaxy 3 and the dreamweaver cs6 live view) the images inside the div take on the height of the outside div with the bottom padding (which is 0px) so it effectively disappears. When I take out the height property altogether the images try to take full size making them way too big.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ID="add_learn_wrapper"><div ID="add_learn_container"><div ID="add_learn_stretch"><div ID="add_learn">
<div class="add_learn_buttons">
<a href=#><img src="images/add-button-up.png" class="button"></a></div>
<div class="add_learn_buttons"><a href=#><img src="images/learn_more_button.png" class="button"></a></div>
<div class="add_learn_buttons"><a href=#><img src="images/report-button.png" class="button"></a>
</div></div></div></div></div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#add_learn_wrapper {
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
#add_learn_wrapper {
    width: 95%;
}   
}
#add_learn_container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 480px;
    min-width: 320px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
#add_learn_container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 10px;
}   
}
#add_learn_stretch {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 54%;
    position: relative;
}
#add_learn {
    display: block;
    Position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
#add_learn2 {
    display: block;
    Position: relative
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.add_learn_buttons {

    height: 32%;
    width: 100%;

}
.add_learn_buttons img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I can't replicate the problem in DreamWeaver CC on mac.  Nor can I replicate it in Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari.  It even looks right in good ol' [Camino](http://caminobrowser.org/) (bless its heart), which I sometimes use for testing because it tends to render things a little closer to older versions of IE.  All this on mac of course.

Comment: Strange! I wish I knew for sure if it was just Galaxy 3 and DW cs6 that have the problem!